# Text and cursor styles changed via JavaScript: browser compatibility problems

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

i have a navigation bar that uses JavaScript to track its state and to update text and cursor style attributes accordingly. This works as intended in Firefox 26.0, but not in Chrome 32.0.1700.76; in Chrome, it appears to do nothing. A short script that illustrates this is:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
var foo_on = true;

function turn_on(x) {
    x.style = "color: #42A6FF; cursor: pointer;";
    x.onmouseover = function () { x.style = "color: #444444; cursor: pointer;"; };
    x.onmouseout = function () { x.style = "color: #42A6FF; cursor: pointer;"; };
}

function turn_off(x) {
    x.style = "color: #BBBBBB; cursor: default;";
    x.onmouseover = null;
    x.onmouseout = null;
}

function toggle(caller) {
    if((foo_on && caller == 'bar') || (!foo_on && caller == 'foo')){ return; }
    if(foo_on){        
        turn_off(foo);
        turn_on(bar);
    }
    else{        
        turn_on(foo);
        turn_off(bar);
    }
    foo_on = !foo_on;
}

function init() {
    foo_on = true;
    turn_on(foo);
    turn_off(bar);
}

window.onload = init();
```

My document layout is:

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <title>Test</title>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='-moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;' unselectable='on'> 
            <a id="foo" onclick="toggle('foo')"> FOO </a>
            <a id="bar" onclick="toggle('bar')"> BAR </a>
        </div>
        <script> {code above} </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is live at http://jsfiddle.net/TF9X7/. Why doesn't this work in Chrome (or what mistake is Firefox forgiving me for)?

Comment: Chrome doens't accept `x.style = "..."` try using `x.style.color = "..."` or `x.setAttribute("style", "...");`

Comment: Or do it right, and use classes …

Comment: @CBroe I'm very new to JavaScript; could you elaborate or provide a reference?

Comment: @RodrigoAssis That works. You're welcome to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > Or do it right, and use classes …
>
> I'm very new to JavaScript; could you elaborate or provide a reference?

Instead of setting the style values directly via JS, you define them in your CSS, using a certain class name – and then you set or remove that class name for the elements:

CSS:

```
a { color: #BBBBBB; cursor: default; }
a.on { color: #42A6FF; cursor: pointer; }
a.on:hover { color: #444444; };
```

JS:

```
function turn_on(x) {
    x.className = "on";
}

function turn_off(x) {
    x.className = "";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TF9X7/2/

Answer (score 2):

I changed some parts of your script. Instead off window.onload, use body onload (`<body onload="Init()">`). The browser first needs to render the DOM in order to capture the objects.

In the function Init(), I changed to capture the element again, because Chrome is returning null, and I changed how you set the properties of style, the correct is object.style.property.

```
<script>
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
var foo_on = true;

function turn_on(x) {
    x.style.color = "#42A6FF";
    x.style.cursor = "pointer";
    x.onmouseover = function () {
        x.style.color = "#444444";
        x.style.cursor = "pointer";
    };
    x.onmouseout = function () {
        x.style.color = "#42A6FF";
        x.style.cursor = "pointer";
    };
}

function turn_off(x) {
    x.style.color = "#BBBBBB";
    x.style.cursor = "default";
    x.onmouseover = null;
    x.onmouseout = null;
}

function toggle(caller) {
    if((foo_on && caller == 'bar') || (!foo_on && caller == 'foo')){
        return;
    }
    if(foo_on){        
        turn_off(foo);
        turn_on(bar);
    }
    else{        
        turn_on(foo);
        turn_off(bar);
    }
    foo_on = !foo_on;
}

function init() {
    foo = document.getElementById('foo');
    bar = document.getElementById('bar');
    foo_on = true;
    turn_on(foo);
    turn_off(bar);
}

body.onload = init();
</script>
```

But I advise you to use the way of CBroe